# I am trying to figure out how to print this array list that I sorted

Tags: java

I was using this code to print out the list of objects and i don't know if it was because i sorted them but it wont print correctly.

```
Collections.sort(cereal);
for (int i = 0; i<cereal.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(cereal.get(i).toString());
}
```

I used this compare method for it and I'm not sure if it works either.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Cereal o) {
    return (int) (this.ratings - o.getRatings());
}
```

Thank you for the feedback.
Here is what is printing:

```
Unit3_7.Cereal@668bc3d5
Unit3_7.Cereal@3cda1055
Unit3_7.Cereal@7a5d012c
Unit3_7.Cereal@3fb6a447
Unit3_7.Cereal@79b4d0f
Unit3_7.Cereal@6b2fad11
```

This is a sample by the way and this is the object:

```
Cereal cereal1 = new Cereal(data[0], data[1],
                                Integer.parseInt(data[2]),
                                Integer.parseInt(data[3]),
                                Integer.parseInt(data[4]),
                                Integer.parseInt(data[5]),
                                Double.parseDouble(data[6]),
                                Double.parseDouble(data[7]),
                                Integer.parseInt(data[8]),
                                Integer.parseInt(data[9]),
                                Integer.parseInt(data[10]),
                                Integer.parseInt(data[11]),
                                Double.parseDouble(data[12]),
                                Double.parseDouble(data[13]),
                                Double.parseDouble(data[14]));
```

I'm getting the data from a csv file that I parsed also, I already confirmed it works and also here is the definition

```
public Cereal(String brandName, String type, int calories, int protein, int fat, int sodium, Double fiber, Double carbohydrates, int sugar, int potassium, int vitamins,int shelf,
            Double weight, Double cups, Double ratings) {
    this.brandName = brandName;
    this.type = type;
    this.calories = calories;
    this.protein = protein;
    this.fat = fat;
    this.sodium = sodium;
    this.fiber = fiber;
    this.carbohydrates = carbohydrates;
    this.sugar = sugar;
    this.potassium = potassium;
    this.vitamins = vitamins;
    this.shelf = shelf;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.cups = cups;
    this.ratings = ratings;
}
```

Comment: So far everything make sense. It seems your class Cereal implements Comparable<Cereal>. What more do you expect ?

Comment: Please define "won't print correctly". Better yet, show us what you're getting.  You might also want to provide us with a sample definition of `cereal`, including the full definition of the class for the objects it contains, that exhibits the problem so that we can reproduce your specific problem.  What you're showing us so far looks reasonable and correct, so we need more information to be able to help you with your problem(s).

Comment: Have you provided your own implementation of toString()?

Comment: You should post the code of your class too. As it’s not clear what type `ratings` is.

Comment: You're getting the expected behavior, as Java doesn't know of a better way to represent your `Cereal` object when it is asked to display it with `println`.  As has been hinted at above, the only thing I think you need to do is add a `toString` method to your `Cereal` object that displays the contents of that object in whatever format you desire.

Comment: omg thanks everyone for the feedback im so stupid for missing the to string method it works fine now im a really bad coder so thanks for the help lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide your own implementation of toString(), e.g.

```
public String toString() {
  return "Brand: " + this.brandName + ", type: " + this.type; // etc, etc
}
```

`Object#toString()`'s default implementation is used when you don't provide/inherit a different one for your class, which just gives you type and memory location info.

Comment: Your last paragraph is a bit misleading.  Lots of built-in classes, and classes in third party modules, provide their own `toString()` method, and primitive types are also printed by Java as their values rather than their memory locations.  So it isn't true that any object except "String" prints using the default `Object.toString()` method.  In fact, for the earlier part of your answer to work, this must not be true.

Comment: Fair comment. It was done in a rush. I’ll correct it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your comparator looks off, you probably want something like this instead:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(Cereal o) {
    return ratings.compareTo(o.getRatings());
}
```

Then, make sure your `Cereal` class has a human-readable `toString()` implementation, eg.:

```java
@Override
public String toString {
    return String.format("Cereal: %s", this.getBrandName());
}
```

Ultimately you can print all `Cereal`s in the list one by one as per your code, or you can print them out all at once like so:

```java
Collections.sort(cereal);
System.out.println(cereal);
```